pywebview error when running demo example
On running the example code:
import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/')
webview.start()

I get a popup window with the message:
We couldn't create the data directory
Microsoft Edge can't read and write to its data directory.
C:\Python312\python.exe.WebView2\EBWebView
Is there a reason why by default it tries to use this random path and is there a way to define a data directory?
Following a bunch of "solutions" to fix other common errors seems to just cause more issues whereas before following similar errors I at least saw an empty window.
Installed webview, .net 4.6.2, edge.
pip installed pywebview and pythonnet.
Ran the demo script in a folder on my desktop.
demo fails with the given error
[pywebview] WebView2 initialization failed with exception:
  (0x80080005): Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))     
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) 
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)        
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__26.MoveNext()
Traceback (most recent call last):

I followed this solution: Python pywebview. Trouble with pythonnet - Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.NullReferenceException. TypeError: 'Assembly' object is not subscriptable
Afterwards I got this error:
Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception. ---> Python.Runtime.BadPythonDllException: Runtime.PythonDLL was not set or does not point to a supported Python runtime DLL. See https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet#embedding-python-in-net ---> System.MissingMethodException: Failed to load symbol PyUnicode_AsUnicode. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified procedure could not be found
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Python.Runtime.Platform.WindowsLoader.GetFunction(IntPtr hModule, String procedureName)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.GetFunctionByName(String functionName, IntPtr libraryHandle)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.GetFunctionByName(String functionName, IntPtr libraryHandle)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Scripts\PythonTest\wv.py", line 3, in <module>
    webview.start()
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webview\__init__.py", line 166, in start
    guilib = initialize(gui)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 134, in initialize
    if not try_import(guis):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 83, in try_import
    if import_func():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webview\guilib.py", line 72, in import_winforms
    import webview.platforms.winforms as guilib
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\webview\platforms\winforms.py", line 13, in <module>
    import clr
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\clr.py", line 6, in <module>
    load()
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py", line 44, in load
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll")
RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dl

I followed the link in the above error and set the PYTHONNET_PYDLL env variable to the python312.dll file but still received the same error.

If possible try installing in a virtual environment ?
